# ManagementEventWatcher есть метод Dispose(), можно ли сделать класс, где он находится IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, интерфейс

Есть следующий код:

```
 public class CustomMEW : IDisposable
{
    private  ManagementEventWatcher _managementEventWatcher;

    private bool _disposed;
    public CustomMEW(EventArrivedEventHandler handler)
    {
        _managementEventWatcher =
            new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("some query"));

        _managementEventWatcher.EventArrived += handler;
    }

    ~CustomMEW()
    {
         Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _managementEventWatcher.Stop();
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _managementEventWatcher.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_managementEventWatcher != null)
            {
                _managementEventWatcher.Dispose();
                _managementEventWatcher = null;
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Нужно ли так реализовывать Dispose для класса, даже если ManagementEventWatcher не имплементирует IDisposable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужно ли так реализовывать Dispose для класса, даже если
>   ManagementEventWatcher не имплементирует IDisposable?

Нужно. `ManagementEventWatcher` на самом деле имплементирует `IDisposable`: он наследуется от `Component`, который, в свою очередь, имплементирует `IDisposable`.

И еще одно дополнение: финализатор вам не нужен, поскольку в классе нет неуправляемых ресурсов. Если они будут в наследниках, то наследники должны будут сами определять финализатор. Если же вы не планируете создавать наследников вашего класса, то реализацию `IDisposable` можно упростить. В таком случае вызовы `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`, а также `protected virtual` метода, вам не нужны.

Подробнее можно прочитать в статье [на Хабре](https://habr.com/post/89720/).

Comment: то есть, можно убрать ~CustomMEW и protected virtual метод? Как из вашей статьи на Хабре: "Если класс владеет управляемыми ресурсами, он может в свою очередь вызывать у них метод Dispose. Никакого дополнительного кода не нужно. Помните, что некоторые классы переименовывают «Dispose» в «Close», поэтому реализация метода Dispose может состоять исключительно из вызовов методов Dispose и Close". Верно?

Comment: а в Dispose просто managementeventwatcher.Dispose, верно?

Comment: @OlegLylok да. И в таком случае пометьте класс как `sealed`.